# Power Apps : Get users from Azure AD to Power Apps view to list table and refresh button for table

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, refresh, powerapps

I am facing issue, with Azure Power Apps. When I add users from Azure AD:

```
AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("Object ID").value
```

And then I get users to my table(my table name: **TableCollection**), but then I have created a refresh for my Table , but it does not refresh it when I click refresh.
My syntax for Refresh button is:

```
AzureAD.RefreshTokens("Object ID")
```

I also have tried to just simple refresh for my table(my table name: TableCollection):

```
Refresh(TableCollection)
```

Does anyone know on this situation how to give correct syntax for refresh button?

Answer (score 0):

`Refresh()` method can only be used on a data source.

So you should add `AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("Object ID").value` into a data source (I name it as `AADData`).

```
Collect( AADData, AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("ed9a0284-3ce5-4ae4-9d0c-68eb8e460330").value)
```

And reference the data source from your table.

Then add a refresh button with the `OnSelect = Clear(AADData); Collect( AADData, AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("Object ID").value)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill in the **TableCollections** you would have used the **Collect** function.

Something like this

```
collect(TableCollections,AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("Object ID").value)
```

In order to refresh this you can use the method `ClearCollect`

The ClearCollect function deletes all the records from a collection. And then adds a different set of records to the same collection.

```
Clearcollect(TableCollections,AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("Object ID").value)
```

So in the above line, the **tablecollection** is cleared and the records are freshly updated from the data source.