# Can we get all Azure AD users list using PoweApps?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerapps

I need to know if there is a possibility to get all Azure AD users using PowerApps or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get all Azure Ad users using PowerApps, whereas you can list the [**details**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/#actions) of a single user or users within a group.

- Make use of **Azure Ad connector** that needs **[administrative permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuread/)** for your account like below:

  - Group.ReadWrite.All
  - User.ReadWrite.All
  - Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Connect Azure AD in the app,

  ***Go to the Data tab -> Add data-> Search Azure AD -> Select Azure Ad connector -> Connect***

To get **users within a group**, make use of below query:

```
Users= AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("Your_Group_ID").value
```

To get **details of a User**, make use of below query:

```
OnSelect = ClearCollect( colAzureUserDetails, AzureAD.GetUser(txtAzureID.Text) )
```

To know more details, please **refer** below links:

[Power Apps Azure AD Group - SPGuides](https://www.spguides.com/power-apps-azure-ad-group/)

[Power Apps : Get users from Azure AD to Power Apps view to list table and refresh button for table - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494271/power-apps-get-users-from-azure-ad-to-power-apps-view-to-list-table-and-refres)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got more clarification from your response.